# How to use Git submodules to install a plugin?

Tags: neovim, git

I just switched to Nvim from Vim, and came to this community.
So, hello all!

I'm doing very primitive config for Nvim and I'm trying to manage my plug-ins using git submodules.

First of all, I'm working on incorporating base16-bright color scheme, and activating it. I did the following:

```
~/.config/nvim $ git init
~/.config/nvim $ git submodule add https://github.com/RRethy/nvim-base16.git
```

and then I added the following line to init.vim

```
colorscheme base16-bright
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add my submodules to the following directory:

```
~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start
```

`plugins` can be anything else, as long as the path matches `pack/*/start`.